# Update Cart's Quantity if same Product added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, shopping-cart

I am new to ROR. I am building e-commerce site. In Shopping Cart if I try to add Products its added if Product is not added before. Now I want if user add same product then its quantity should be incremented.

Here is add_to_cart method in carts_controller.rb Thanks in advance.

```
def add_to_cart
  @cart = Cart.find_by_Product_id_and_User_id( params[:product_id], current_user.id)
   if @cart.nil?
    @cart = Cart.create(:User_id => current_user.id, :Product_id => params[:product_id], :Quantity => '1')
  else 
    @cart.update(:Quantity +=> '1')
  end
    redirect_to view_cart_path
end
```

Comment: Use Capital words only for class name, modules, constant etc.
NOT for attributes name, hash keys etc.

Rewrite your code and say what is your problem? what exactly does not work

Comment: @gotva :  It's solved by trying...
else 
        [at]cart=Cart.find_by_Product_id(params[:product_id])
        [at]cart.Quantity += 1
        [at]cart.save
      end

Comment: @gotva : thanks for your guidance now I will take care of it during naming of attribute..

Answer (score 1):

Your schema seems strange:  why do carts have a product id?  This suggests that a cart "belongs_to" a product, which is wrong.  I'd have expected each User to have a single Cart, and a cart to have a list of Products via a join table.  Something like this:

```
class User 
  has_one :cart
end

#user_id
class Cart
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :cart_products
  has_many :products, :through => :cart_products
end

#cart_id, product_id, :quantity
class CartProduct
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
end

#various fields to do with the specific product
class Product
  has_many :cart_products
  has_many :carts, :through => :cart_products
end
```

If this is the schema, then i would handle quantity updating like so:

```
#in Cart class
def add_product(product)
  if cart_product = self.cart_products.find_by_product_id(product.id)
    cart_product.quantity += 1
    cart_product.save
    cart_product
  else
    self.cart_products.create(:product_id => product.id, :quantity => 1)
  end
end
```